# Gerund Separate Words

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, gerunds

My friend and I have been debating if adding 'ing' to a word makes it its own word. We said Webster would be the final answer for the debate. A search on Webster though brought back the root word as the word with the gerund version as an alteration. To me that means the root word is the word. Is this correct?

The word in question is motoring.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motoring

If we had a paper edition of the dictionary I'm arguing that `motoring` would not be listed. Is this correct?

Comment: This really depends on what you mean by "its own word".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Motoring" is for quite some time past this kindergarten stage of words that you're talking about :-)

Also, use the proper Merriam-Webster:-)

> **motoring**
>
> noun
>
> plural -s
>
> :  the act or recreation of riding in or driving an automobile
>
> Origin of MOTORING
>
> from gerund of 3motor
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

"Motoring" is a full-fledged word these days.

Comment: _-ing_ words that have made the conversion to noun (accepting quantification, plural formation: _seven etchings_) are known as deverbal nouns. They are certainly not verbal nouns in this usage.

Answer (score 1):

Paper dictionaries will use the accepted "dictionary" form of the word, whether it is the singular form of a noun or the bare infinitive of a verb. The dictionary will typically show the transformations these words undergo, much as you noticed with the online dictionaries.

You may see the gerund form of a verb if that form has a meaning distinct from the bare infinitive. Similarly, you may see the plural form of a noun under various circumstances, whether it is more common than the singular (*datum* and *data*, *criterion* and *criteria*) or if it has a distinct meaning (*person* and *people*, where *people* can also be pluralized as *peoples*).

As far as I know, this is standard not just in English, but other languages as well.